# Jenny wants to draw a mystic rose for a math-art competition. She wonders how many lines (chords) she will have to draw. Jenny focuses ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Jenny wants to draw a mystic rose for a math-art competition. She wonders how many lines (chords) she will have to draw.
Jenny focuses on one point, P, and notices that 19 lines start there.

A.) Fill in the following table to determine a pattern

[image]

(5)(4) = 20, (6)(5) = 30, (7)(6) = 42

B.) Since there are 20 points in her mystic rose, she predicts there must be 20 x 19 lines. However there are not 20 x 19 lines for a 20-point mystic rose. How many are there?

20(19/2) = 190 lines

C.) How many lines will an n-point mystic rose have?

n[(n - 1)/2]

I am not sure if my answers are correct, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It look's right, but it is not clear what even a mystic rose is? Is there supposed to be a diagram. Nevermind, it looks mystic rose is a real term that I've just never heard of. You're answers are correct.

Comment: @AlanAbraham thank you so much!

Comment: @AlanAbraham How are you certain that the answers are correct? For a 4-point mystic rose, part A says that there are 12 lines (based on the table), but part C says that there are $4 \times 3 / 2 = 6$ lines (based on OP's answer). Hence, to me, OP's answer is most likely incorrect. $\quad$ I agree that we'd need to know what a "mystic rose" is in order to figure out what the answers are.

Comment: Oh wait nvm, those answers might not be correct. Sorry. I'm not too sure. I looked at pictures of mystic roses, and it seemed to match with OPs answers. I don't know how to get the answers in the table.

Comment: @CalvinLin  One method for drawing a [mystic rose](https://nrich.maths.org/6703) is to draw a chord from each point on the circle to every other point on the circle, which gives $n(n - 1)$ lines.  However, each chord is drawn twice using this method, once from each endpoint.  The number of chords that can be drawn using $n$ points on a circle is $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes I understand that, and that was my expectation based on my assumptinos/guesses. However, it contradicts the information given in the question. (Perhaps OP filled in the right column themselves, and had the wrong information?)